# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128) jinja2

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, jinja2

i am using jinja2 for templating, it works well when i have ascii name. but when name having unicode data, it throws error. following is my sample code.

```
#Python code
metaData = {"fname": u"Cec\xedlia Tom\xe1s","data":[{"cName":u"Cec\xedlia Tom\xe1s"},{"cName":"ASCII string"}]}
j2_env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(pConfig["templatePage"]),
                     trim_blocks=True)
t = j2_env.get_template('Content.html')
content = t.render(**metaData)

/*jinja2 template*/
var fname = '{{fname}}';
```

getting

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried with

```
metaData["fname"] = metaData["fname"].encode('utf-8') and
metaData["data"][0]["cName"] = metaData["data"][0]["cName"].encode('utf-8')
```

but still i am getting same error.

Comment: At which point does the error occur?  In the call to `render()` (which seems odd, jinja is unicode aware), or at some other point?

Comment: @donkopotamus i am developing website in core python and problem was with main control file that returns content written as  str(content) here most of time content is ascii but when unicode comes it trigger error. However, controller file error throws in apache error log without much description, i was wrong to determine problem. Thanks. It gets solved now.